# Send gmail and live/hotmail emails

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008

For my application I have code to send emails for live/hotmail, but not for gmail, that doesn't work I tried to build a check for it, to see what account is used to send the e-mail but it's not working, when I try to send an Gmail email. Here is the code I use for the check:

```
MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
            msg.To.Add(txtAan.Text);
            msg.From = new MailAddress(txtGebruikersnaam.Text);
            msg.Subject = txtOnderwerp.Text;
            msg.Body = txtBericht.Text;

            string smtpcheck = txtGebruikersnaam.Text;
            smtpcheck.Substring(Math.Max(0, smtpcheck.Length - 10));

            SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
            if (smtpcheck.ToLower() == "@gmail.com")
            {
                smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
                smtp.Port = 25;
            }
            else if(smtpcheck.ToLower() != "@gmail.com")
            {
                smtp.Host = "smtp.live.com";
                smtp.Port = 587;
            }
            smtp.EnableSsl = true;
            smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(txtGebruikersnaam.Text, txtWachtwoord.Text);
            smtp.Send(msg);
```

This code gives me an error when I try to send an E-mail by using Gmail, can somebody give me a little help with this problem? And yes I also tried the port: 465 and 587 for gmail, so I don't think that is the problem either.

Comment: what error does it give?

Comment: gmail is either refusing your connection (in which case you would get some kind of exception when sending the email) or it is accepting it then discarding it as spam.

Comment: Mailbox unavailable. The server response was: 5.7.3 Requested action aborted; user not authenticated, it is an smtp exception

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line doesn't change the value of smtpcheck

```
  smtpcheck.Substring(Math.Max(0, smtpcheck.Length - 10));
```

you need to write

```
  smtpcheck = smtpcheck.Substring(Math.Max(0, smtpcheck.Length - 10));
```

As result your if condition fails and you fall to send the mail always with live.com

EDIT: For gmail, this code is confirmed to work

```
 SmtpClient sc = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");
 NetworkCredential nc = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
 sc.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
 sc.Credentials = nc;
 sc.EnableSsl = true;
 sc.Port = 587;
```

Comment: I edited my code, to your code and now when I click the send button, it takes like 20 seconds, and then it tells met that the smtp timed out, is there anything I can do about it? maybe with smtp.timout?

Answer (score 0):

```
try
{
     MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
     SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");

     mail.From = new MailAddress("your_email_address@gmail.com");
     mail.To.Add("to_address");
     mail.Subject = "Test Mail";
     mail.Body = "This is for testing SMTP mail from GMAIL";

     SmtpServer.Port = 587;
     SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password");
     SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;

     SmtpServer.Send(mail);
     MessageBox.Show("mail Send");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
     MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
}
```